# How can I send a string to an external text editor?

Tags: windows, python-3.7

I want to display a string to the user using an external text editor (notepad++) so that they can search, edit etc. and save to file if they so choose.  The string is about 100MB-1GB in size.  I want to avoid writing to a temporary file and then opening it in the text editor as this involves writing the whole string to disk and then reading it from disk.  I would like to minimise the delay.  Can I somehow load it straight from memory into the text editor?

In linux I could write/read to tmpfs to keep it in memory but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent in Windows.  Even with tmpfs, there is an uneccesary comsumption of memory.

Ultimately something like this:

```
import os
with open('myfile.bin', 'rb') as f:
    whole_file: bytes = f.read()
my_str: str = process_bytes(whole_file)
os.startfile(my_str)
```

Comment: If all you're after is a simple display, you could create a very basic GUI to display it directly from memory

Comment: @dantechguy:  Unfortunately not.  I want the user to be able to show/hide non-printing charcters, search in different ways and save the data to file if they choose.  I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Many editors support reading from stdin (typically by passing `-` as the filename to edit).  Then you can write your content through a pipe.  Once the editor closes the input pipe all the pipe buffers are freed and the data exists only in the edit buffers.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Could you give a commnad line syntax example?  My attempts to send "MyText" to notepadd++ have resulted in *'"MyText"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.* and also corrupting the notepadd++ executable by appending "MyText to it!